# Remove All in One Seo from Posts for Contributors

Tags: posts, metabox, user-roles, plugin-all-in-one-seo

I am using latest version of [All In One Seo Package](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/).

How can I remove metaboxes from posts for User Role: "Contributors"?

Answer (score 0):

This effectively removes metaboxes IF the current user is a contributor. This does not remove any admin column data ( like SEO Description and such when viewing pages ). You need to define which post types to run it on in the `$post_types` array which will then loop through and target specifically the `aiosp` metabox ( that's the metabox ID ) and removes it.

```
function wpse_205080() {
    if( current_user_can( 'contributor' ) ) {
        $post_types = array( 'page', 'post' );

        foreach( $post_types as $type ) {
            remove_meta_box( 'aiosp', $type, 'normal' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'do_meta_boxes', 'wpse_205080' );
```

There's a ton of questions regarding removing metaboxes if you search through the site. The big thing is taking advantage of your browser's [Developer Tools](http://devtoolsecrets.com/) to find the ID.

Comment: Unfortunately above code didn't work. I login in Dashboard and try to create a post as Contributor and All in One Seo Pack metabox is inside post. Any suggestion? Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

There is a [post on the WordPress.org forum for All in One SEO Pack for WordPress about this very subject.](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/restricting-access-to-non-admins-within-posts) You may want to use a role manager plugin to assist with this and manage that users role.